# How to get a literal date range query in solr working using the TZ parameter

Tags: solr

A GET request with the URL

> http://localhost:9999/solr/foo_core/select?q=event_name:video-start&fq=event_dt:[2018-07-09T18:38:00Z TO 2018-07-09T18:39:00Z]&TZ=Asia/Kolkata

is returning the same result as when the TZ parameter is NOT specified. It seems that the TZ parameter is not overriding UTC("Zulu").

Answer (score 0):

That's not how the TZ parameter works. In those cases you can convert the timestamp to UTC before sending it to Solr (since *any datetime* in Solr is already in UTC), and your range will be correct.

[The TZ parameter](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/6_6/working-with-dates.html#WorkingwithDates-TZ) is for *date rounding* and for *date arithmetic* inside Solr (for example range faceting):

> By default, all date math expressions are evaluated relative to the UTC TimeZone, but the TZ parameter can be specified to override this behaviour, by forcing all date based addition and rounding to be relative to the specified time zone.

Comment: Thanks. Please do forgive me for asking again; "isnt a time range expression also a date arithmetic expression" ? Can you please state two examples which highlight the use of the TZ parameter ?

Comment: i am sorry that i had a time out while posing the above question. Here is it once again -> Thanks. Please do forgive me for asking again; isnt the statement "a date time range expression involving time literals is also a date arithmetic expression" true ? What does then 'TZ override' mean ? Can you please state two non-faceting query examples involving dates (with or without date literals) where the TZ parameter is used to demonstrate the 'override' behavior? Thanks once again.

Comment: Anything that rounds a date - i.e. NOW/MONTH would use the TZ parameter to calculate when it actually turned over to the new month.